# How to configure the tiger VNC in RHEL 6 to enable remote login after reboot?

Tags: redhat, rhel6

How to configure the tiger VNC in RHEL 6 to enable remote login after reboot? Currently, I could remote login to it when it has login already. But if I remotely restart the server, it would not allow me to remotely login again. It says **connection refused**.

Comment: Is iptables running? `/etc/init.d/iptables status`

Comment: This is how i resolved the problem. Go to System -> Startup App. Pref. -> Options -> Remember Currently Running Application. Of course you need to make sure vncserver service is up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chkconfig` command can be used to manage services on Redhat distros such as Fedora & CentOS.

```
% sudo chkconfig --levels 345 vncserver on
```

You can see which run levels it's enabled to start automatically in with this command:

```
% chkconfig --list vncserver
```

Here's a [good article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4445) on the use of `chkconfig` if you want to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the startup script run as part of the boot process. You can use `chkconfig` tool on red hat to do so. Something like the following:

```
$ sudo chkconfig service_name on
```